# Find value with specific filter in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm bit confused, I want to calculate status "canceled", only "ready_to_ship" with buyerfailedDeliveryReason = "cancel-buyer" and "cancel-system"

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyHje.png)

I'm already using this DAX but not still sum value status canceled too

```
Return Lazada = 
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        'All Lazda',
        'All Lazda'[buyerFailedDeliveryReturnInitiator] = "cancel-buyer" || 'All Lazda'[buyerFailedDeliveryReturnInitiator] = "cancel-system" &&
        NOT('All Lazda'[status] = "canceled")
    ),
    'All Lazda'[paidPrice]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you can try to wrap your piped predicates ( `OR` statements ) so that they are evaluated together:

```
Return Lazada =
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        'All Lazda',
        NOT ( 'All Lazda'[status] = "canceled" )
            && ( 'All Lazda'[buyerFailedDeliveryReturnInitiator] = "cancel-buyer"
            || 'All Lazda'[buyerFailedDeliveryReturnInitiator] = "cancel-system" )
    ),
    'All Lazda'[paidPrice]
)
```

So this will aggregate the `paidPrice` for all rows in `All Lazda` where the `status` is NOT "canceled" **and** the `Initiator` is either `cancel-buyer` or `cancel-system`.

If you want to instead evaluate only those rows where `status = "ready_to_ship"` (instead of evaluating all rows that are specifically NOT `status = "canceled"`, then write this in your formula instead:

```
Return Lazada =
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        'All Lazda',
        'All Lazda'[status] = "ready_to_ship"
            && ( 'All Lazda'[buyerFailedDeliveryReturnInitiator] = "cancel-buyer"
            || 'All Lazda'[buyerFailedDeliveryReturnInitiator] = "cancel-system" )
    ),
    'All Lazda'[paidPrice]
)
```